# Which script gets invoked from my eclipse when starting weblogic server?

Tags: eclipse, macos, weblogic

I setup weblogic to run on my Mac. I am trying to start weblogic from eclipse on port 80 but it doesn't start. I can start the server using sudo on a terminal. I am not able to figure out which script gets called when I start the server from eclipse?

The error that I am getting is:

There are 1 nested errors:

weblogic.management.ManagementException: Unable to obtain File lock on /local/bea/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/AdminServer.lok : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /local/bea/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/AdminServer.lok (Permission denied)
    at weblogic.management.internal.ServerLocks.getServerLock(ServerLocks.java:151)
    at weblogic.management.internal.ServerLocks.getServerLock(ServerLocks.java:58)
    at weblogic.management.internal.DomainDirectoryService.start(DomainDirectoryService.java:73)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:749)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:488)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:446)
    at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:67)

> 

Comment: can u delete /local/bea/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/AdminServer.lok if it exists and try again

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Somehow I need to start the server as sudo. The error message that I got is:
There are 1 nested errors:

weblogic.store.PersistentStoreException: java.io.IOException: [Store:280045]The file store directory "/local/bea/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/data/store/diagnostics" is not a directory
Caused by: weblogic.store.PersistentStoreException: java.io.IOException: [Store:280045]The file store directory "/local/bea/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/data/store/diagnostics" is not a directory

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses the `startWeblogic.sh` and `setDomainEnv.sh` from your domain's bin folder. Make sure that these are executable. Maybe you need to execute `chmod +x *sh` in the bin folder.